# AngularJS : Why when using back button on the browser my promises return before resolve with previous value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, factory

Hi here is my code when I run the factory this one gets resolved before with the old data from the page before. if I put break points I get a hit on the callback before the promise is resolved

`$scope.formElementsData = response;` get there before  `deferred.resolve(formElements);`.

```js
 // when I call it after using the back button 
 GetInputControlItemsService.getInputControlItems($routeParams.project +','+ $routeParams.templateid ).then(function(response) {
     $scope.formElementsData = response;
 });

app.factory('GetInputControlItemsService', [
    '$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
        var apiCall, deferred, factory, _getInputControlItems;
        factory = {};
        deferred = $q.defer();
        apiCall = 'api/GetProjectInputControlItems/?projectAndTempletaeId=';
        _getInputControlItems = function(projectAndTempletaeId) {
            $http.get(webBaseUrl + apiCall + projectAndTempletaeId).success(function(formElements) {
                deferred.resolve(formElements);
            }).error(function(err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
        factory.getInputControlItems = _getInputControlItems;
        return factory;
    }
])
```

Y also tried

```js
GetInputControlItemsService.getInputControlItems($routeParams.project +','+ $routeParams.templateid ).then(function(response) {
              return response;
            }).then(function(response){
               $scope.formElementsData = response;
              });
```

and still not working any idea how to use this along with the back button of the browser   ?

Also I notice if I call a factory inside a function for a search feature,  it does the same thing it runs inside the callback before the promise is deferred.
So I end up calling it without promises and now it works here is the code without the factory service.

```js
 $scope.goSearch = function() {
                if ($scope.searchKey !== '') {
                    $http.get(webBaseUrl + apiCall + $scope.searchKey).success(function(results) {
                        $scope.projects = results;
                    });
                }
            };
```

Comment: Problem  needs a far better explanation and question could use some better formatting to make it readable

Comment: Has anyone really been far as decided to use even go want to do look more like?